# Binary search in ordered QVector

Tags: c++, linux, qt5.5

I've ordered `QVector<QString>` by `qSort`. I'd like to get index of specified `QString`, but `qBinarySearch` returns Java-style iterator allowing to move next/back or pointer to `QString` (because `QVector::iterator` is `typedef T*`). How can I get index of element without iterate for each element and check. Is the only way make own binary search method (I know how, but why invent wheel again?)?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms-obsolete.html those algorithms are obsolete, and you are recommended to use `std::binary_search` (or `std::lower_bound`) instead. They return random access iterators, so converting them to an index is cheap and easy.

Comment: The actual question is hidden in irrelevant detail. It is about getting an index from an iterator.

Comment: @juanchopanza Well, it might be. If the OP is correct that `qBinarySearch` returns a non-standard Java-style iterator then the standard techniques wouldn't work.

Comment: I wasn't know that subtraction "begin - iterator" returns index. I've made that in my method.

Comment: @patrykbajos you meant iterator-begin